# Div height doesn't toggle

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to toggle div's height using jQuery.
I have this html code:

```
<div id="content" align="center">
<p class="welcome-message"><b><img src="./dashboard/images/website-management.png">
WEBSITEs UNDER MANAGEMENT</b></p>

<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td>http://mysite.example.com/</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td>8/7/2012</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td>8/6/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>

       
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td>http://mysite.example.com/my_hotjobsubmission</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td>5/31/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td>5/31/2014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td>Awesome hosting</td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>
 
       
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td>08/05/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td>Awesome hosting</td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p></div>

   
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td>http://mysite.example.com/my_hotjobsubmission</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td>5/31/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td>5/31/2014</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>


    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td>Awesome hosting</td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>

   
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p>
<p class="welcome-message">
<!-- email account -->
</p><div id="website-acc">
<a class="dropdown-link" href="#"><p class="fb-head"><img src="./dashboard/images/acc_arr.png" style="margin-right:5px;"><b>WEBSITE </b></p></a>
    <div>
<div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
<table width="50%" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>Website URL:</td>
       <td></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Date of creation:</td>
       <td>08/05/2013</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Expiration date:</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hosting Package:</td>
    <td>Awesome hosting</td>
  </tr>
  
</tbody></table>

</div>

   
    </div>
</div>
<!-- end email acc-->
<p></p></div>
```

and I'm using this JavaScript code in the head:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var dd = $(".dropdown-container");

  $("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dd.hide("fast");
    $(this).next().show("fast");
  });

  $(document).click(function() {
    dd.hide();
  });

  dd.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
</script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybup4/1/).
Now the problem is that div's are not showing or hiding, can anybody tell me what the problem is and how can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like it should work. Can't reproduce. Can you create a Fiddle?

Comment: @putvande question updated - http://jsfiddle.net/Ybup4/

Comment: Is that an empty Fiddle?

Comment: Your fiddle is empty :)

Comment: @putvande http://jsfiddle.net/Ybup4/1/ now?

Comment: In your fiddle demo you have not included the jquery file.

Comment: you can also use jquery animate function for height and toggle also as an another method it will more easy then this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. Actually the `$(this).next()` will fetch `div`, which is the parent of `.dropdown-container`. That is why `.dropdown-container` is not displaying

```
$("a.dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dd.hide("fast");
    $(this).next().find('.dropdown-container').show();

  });
```

JS Fiddle demo

> http://jsfiddle.net/t7FL9/1/

Comment: it gives me Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined. should i put  something in the <body> tag,use onload or something like that?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle url. Sorry, forgot to add the single quotes for the `$('body')`

Comment: @dimesh this is happening on my website